# Apply dplyr::count_ to many data frames

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, lapply

I got error for apply count_ to all my dataframes. I can manually apply to single  dataframe, but when I tried `lapply`, it showed error

> ```
> Error in UseMethod("groups") :
>   no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "character"
> ```

I want to find the unique pairs of longitude and latitute in my dataset. For single dataframe I used `dplyr::count_(d, vars = c('longitude','latitute '))`, which return a table of pairs of values and the count number. I want to check the unique pairs in each of dataframe and store them in separate files. Currently I tried put all my dataframes in a list and used `for` loop.

For single data frame, I used

```
dplyr::count_(CA, vars = c('locationlongitude','locationlatitude'))
###it returns output like this

   locationlongitude locationlatitude     n
                <dbl>            <dbl> <int>
 1             -72.0             42.6    47
 2             -72.0             42.6    69
 3             -71.8             42.6    59
 4             -71.7             42.5    93
 5             -71.7             42.5    65
```

Then I want to apply to all my data frames

```
for (i in files) {
    nam <- paste("B_", i)
    assign(nam, dplyr::count_(i, vars = c('locationlongitude', 'locationlatitude')))
}
```

`files` is a list of all my dataframes' name and I expected created dataframes begin with B_+dataframesname to store my unique locations from each data frame. But there is

> ```
> Error  in UseMethod("groups") : 
>   no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "character".
> ```

I also tried to create files as a list and each elements will be the dataframe but I got another error when doing that:

> ```
> Error in assign(nam, dplyr::count_(i, vars = c("locationlongitude", "locationlatitude"))) :
>   variable names are limited to 10000 bytes
> In addition: Warning message: In assign(nam, dplyr::count_(i, vars = c("locationlongitude", "locationlatitude"))) :
>   only the first element is used as variable name
> ```

I believe there should be a efficient way to apply function to multiple data frame and return another data frame. But I'm stuck. I'd appreciated any comments!

Comment: Use [a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/4497050) or a nested list-column of a data frame, or just a single bigger data frame with another grouping column. But don't use `for` to iterate `assign`. And the functions suffixed with `_` have been deprecated in favor of tidy eval, but that's additional complication you can ignore for now.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I  changed code and use a list of data frames as                     
 list_df<- lapply(ls(pattern="df.+"), function(x) get(x)).        But if I don't use for loop, should I use lapply or any other options? many thanks.

Comment: I used list of df and lapply, it works. Thank you!  But could you explain a little why the loop and assign is not recommended?

Comment: The key is not to litter your global environment with data frames, but to store them all in a list from the start, e.g. with `list_of_data_frames <- lapply(ls(pattern = "csv"), read.csv)`. Then you can iterate over your list really easily with `lapply` or the like without keeping track of names or worrying about what state data frames are in or how to clean up everything.

Comment: As for why _not_ to use `for` and `assign`, there are simpler ways to write code that are less likely to have unintended consequences. `for` is almost never necessary in R, and requires extra attention to use well, with initialization and preallocation. `lapply` takes care of this for you, though it's not inherently faster. When possible, the best option is to vectorize everything. `assign` is a function that is only appropriately used in the context of operating on the language itself, which is advanced R programming. Outside of that context, it makes code difficult to read.